# How to receive INSTALL_SHORTCUT broadcast on Android

Tags: android, shortcut, launcher, receiver

I try to receive an event everytime a new shortcut on the Homescreen/Luncher was created. After my app receive the event I like to modify the shortcut. My current configuration is listed below, but I never receive an event.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />    
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<application>
  <receiver  
     android:name=".InstallShortcutReceiver"
     android:permission="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
</application>
```

Is my idea possible ?

Best Regards,
André

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. When I shortcut is created using drap and drop from the menu no INSTALL_SHORTCUT event is published.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the permission line from the receiver? The permission you specify in a receiver like that is the permission necessary to call it, not for it to receive broadcasts.

Comment: I removed the permission but it still doesn't work. I'm using the android studios nexus emulator.